# Anther Solution For Running Python file from C# With out ironpython

Tags: c#, python

i am not **python** permanent user how to run **python script** by click event from **visual studio 2012**.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute any Python implementation as a child process using command line arguments, stdin, stdout, even sockets etc. to communicate.

Alternatively if you want one process but not IronPython you could use the C-API for CPython (python.org) with PInvoke or some native code. You can either embed it in your process or you could make your C# into a module (extending).